Chrome not navigating to URL when serenity version changed
I am using serenity-cucumber to automate my tests integrated with maven. Everything was working till serenity version changed.
Recently changed serenity version to 4.x.x. When I try to run my test, chrome browser open but not navigating to URL.
To me, compatibility between chrome driver and chrome browser is not an issue as driver is downloaded automatic as I am setting autodownload = true in serenity property file
Below is error:
net.serenitybdd.model.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: 'java.util.function.Supplier org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Contents.utf8String(java.lang.CharSequence)'

